# QGIS split polygons does not create new polygon

Tags: qgis, splitting

I am fairly new to QGIS.

I need to split one polygon into two. I have done this with one of the Split tools (and don't remember which one, unfortunately).
It created a line where I want the split but there is still just one polygon. You can see in the picture where I only selected one.
I am not able to easily delete the line and deleting some of the nodes deletes either part or the entire polygon.

I need to make a separate polygon for the left and right side.

Any suggestions?

[image]

---

After several trials and errors, I managed to do it in another version of my shp with the Split Features tool.
Too bad I kept working with the messed up file all afternoon.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402990/88814

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar you are using the "Split Parts" tool instead of using the "Split Features" tool just on the left of it. That one should do just what you need.

Comment: Actually, I just found out I must have messed up my layer completely because I cannot select the polygon I need for the splitting. It works for the right part in the picture but not for the left part. And now both options give me error message "No part split done: The geometry is invalid. Please repair before trying to split it." I just spent the entire afternoon editing my polygons, I really hope I don't need to start from scratch :(

Comment: Try buffering your polygon with a distance of 0, maybe this solves the problem. Otherwise, try Check Geometry plugin.